# Solve the initial value problem $y'=e^{-y^2}+1, \, y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the ODE(ordinary differential equation) $$y'=e^{-y^2}+1, y(0)=0.$$ Which of the following statements are true for given ODE?

$P: $ The ODE has unique solution on $\mathbb R.$

$Q:$ The solution of given ODE is bounded on its maximal interval of existence.

According to my analysis, statement $P$ is incorrect because it is an autonomous ODE with the function $f(y) = e^{-y^2} + 1$, and its partial derivative $f_y$ is continuous on the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$. So solution will be unique but no guarantee on full real line. However, I have doubts about statement $Q$. Please provide your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: $|y'| \le 2$ guarantees the existence of the solution on all of $\Bbb R$ (the solution can not “explode”).

Comment: @MartinR So according to you what is the answer? Thank you .

Comment: @MartinR So solution will be unique on full $\mathbb R$? But need on bounded on  $\mathbb R$? P is but Q is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

(P) Show that the function $u \mapsto 1 + e^{-u^2}$ is Lipschitz continuous on $\Bbb R$, e.g., $e^{-y^2} - e^{-x^2} \leq 2 (y - x)$. Now apply a standard existence–uniqueness theorem.

(Q) Since $y'(t) \geq 1$ for all $t$, for $t \geq 0$ we have $$\int_0^t y'(\tau) \,d\tau \geq \int_0^t 1 \,dt .$$

Comment: Standard existence and uniqueness theorem is about locally? Can it say solution will be unique in whole real line?

Comment: is it ok that lip constant is $2?$

Comment: I am unable to understand how it is globally Lip with Lip constant as $2.$

Comment: In fact (since the function is differentiable) one can improve the Lipschitz constant to the maximum of the absolute value of the derivative of $u \mapsto 1 + e^{-u^2}$, namely $\sqrt{\frac2e}$, but a coarser estimate gives 2.

Comment: Thank you sir ....